# What's the best way to distribute the header files of my C++ shared library?

Tags: c++, header

So I have my shared library libMySharedLibrary.so. And it has a bunch of header files in their own folders, etc. What is the best/standard way to group those header files and distribute them to the clients of my shared library?

Comment: Even if you would get answers for this question, how do you think to sort out _the best_ from all of these opinions?

Comment: Isn't there a standard way to do so? You just zip or tar or whatever and give to the person?

Comment: No there aren't standards really.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There *are* standards. Most `Linux` distributions are `GNU` based operating systems and follow `GNU` standards. Third party software usually follows suit.

Comment: @Galik Since when linux is considered _standard_? Sorry I'm an enthusiastic linux user, but calling it _standard_ goes way too far. Better advise the OP to just zip everything together, and let their clients decide where to extract the stuff for development.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Linux is not a standard it is a `kernel`. Most "Linux" distros run the `GNU` operating system and usually follow various standards. Distros do not just bung stuff anywhere.

Comment: @Galik Sorry to tell you you're wrong: Linux **is not a kernel**, that's part of it yes. But linux is an operating system, coming in various configurations and distributions. But why should we argue on an off-topic opinion based question?

Answer (score 2):

They will typically go in `${prefix}/include/mylibrary` where `${prefix}` is the installation root (often `/usr` for a distro and `/usr/local` for distribution 3rd party libs).

This way programs include them like:

```
#include <mylibrary/header.h>
```

For more information checkout the [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html).

Most Linux based systems are `GNU` based operating systems and follow `GNU` standards. But there *are* differences.

Different distros have different package management systems for installing software but most distros use either one of two (rpm & deb). Many build systems abstract away the precise locations for things like headers and libraries so if you use something like autotools it allows the person doing the install to select the location or use the distro's defaults.

You should be prepared for minor differences between distros so you may have to prepare specific install packages for some things.

Comment: so can I just provide a zip/tar with `mylibrary/myfolder/myheader.h` entries?

Comment: Ah we're talking about linux. Any hints for windows, android or whatever else?

Comment: @PeterMel Different distros have different package management systems for installing software but most distros use either one of two (rpm & deb). Many build systems abstract away the precise locations for things like headers and libraries so if you use something like `autotools` it allows the person doing the install to select the location or use the distro's defaults.